# How to dynamically remember last link with php

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, http-referer

how can I dynamically remember last link with php? For instance, this is the parent page's url,

```
http://website.com/#/events/upcoming-events/
```

note that I have a hash in all URLs.

and this is the child page's,

```
http://website.com/#/events/upcoming-events/event-1/
```

On the child page I have a link to go back to the parent page,

```
<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];?>" class="button-back">Back</a>
```

`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];` only gives me `http://website.com/ of course.`

How do I get around to this then?

Comment: You can't determine hash URLS on the server side, becase clinet doesn't send anything after # symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be difficult to do on server side but you can do this on client side using `jQuery`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var hrefParts = location.href.split('/');
    hrefParts.splice(hrefParts.length - 2);
    $('.button-back').attr('href', hrefParts.join('/') + '/');
});
```